# Using JQuery to toggle between symbols

Tags: jquery

I want my symbol in `#menu` to change from symbol `&#9776` to `X` when &#9776 is clicked and I would like to toggle between these. This is how I tried to write it, but the symbols don't change. How do I code this correctly?

```
$("#menu").click(function() {
    if ($("#menu").html() == '&#9776') {
        $("#menu").html('X');
    } else {
        $("#menu").html('&#9776');
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Have you tried using `☰` instead of `&#9776`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#menu").click(function(){    
    var element=$(this);
    var symbol = $('<div/>', {html:'&#9776'});
    if (element.html() === $(symbol).html()) {
        element.html('X');
    }else 
    {
        element.html('&#9776');        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">&#9776</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` instead of referencing your element by its `id` every time and use `===` identical operator to exactly match your string. Use like this

```
$("#menu").click(function(){    
    var element=$(this);
    if (element.html() === '&#9776') {
        element.html('X');
    }else {
        element.html('&#9776');        
    }
});
```

Comment: and cache the `$(this)`

Comment: `$(this)` aside, is the only difference that you used `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @j08691 looks like it, it be much easier to match the X than the entity haha

Comment: I tried your code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing happens and the symbol stays '&#9776'.

Comment: can you paste your html in the question